# Should use `.merge()` or multiple `.set()` to update multiple fields in ImmutableJS?

Tags: javascript, merge, immutable.js

I'm currently using `immutablejs` in my React project to update Redux data store.

Given:

```
const state = new Map({ key0: 'value0' });
```

Example using `.merge()`:

```
state.merge({
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
});
```

Example using multiple `.set()`:

```
state
  .set('key1', 'value1')
  .set('key2', 'value2');
```

Which way should be recommended?

Comment: actually both are fine, there has no performance differences between them, just the purpose for both of them are different.

Comment: just 1 thing to point out, if using `.set()` it need to be reassign to the variable `state = state.set('key1', 'value1')` else it won't work

Comment: @Dean but `immutablejs` always returns a new set of data. If you need to reassign, you have to do the same even using `.merge()` or `.set()`.

Comment: my bad, it require on both.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `merge` method will call to `set` in implementation. You can see in [ImmutableJS](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/methods/merge.js)

So from my view, using `set` is better performance (a little bit). You can choose whatever you like

Answer (score 1):

each call of .set() creates new Immutable instance, so chaining it leads to unnecessary memory pollution. 
You should use it with [.withMutations()](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/withMutations), which will produce only one Immutable instance.

.merge() internally use .set() and .withMutations(), but it also calls some extra code responsible for handling multiple merge arguments.